# How to lower composite reliability

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, reliability, consistency, composite

at the moment I'm evaluating a survey which contains some constructs with too high composite reliability values. The CR (composite reliability) values are above .95 which indicates redundant items. In consequence to this I nneed to reduce the CR because it is indicating that there are redundant items. I want to identify which items are redudant.

My question is:
Is there a solid way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Note that there is no need to give thanks on advance or sign your name at the bottom of a question.

Comment: Your final question is a little unclear - are you essentially asking "how can I decide which is redundant"?

Comment: Exactly this is the question. I need to reduce the CR because it is indicating that there are redundant items. I want to identify which items are redudant.

Comment: Thanks - it might be a good idea to edit this into the question itself ("edit" button is just below your post) as not everyone reads the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Items are redundant as a function of other items.

If I ask your height in inches, and your height in cm, one of them is redundant. Which one? Both, or neither.  It doesn't matter which one you use, just pick one.

Are you trying to reduce the length of your scale?  Typically shorter versions of scales are developed through validity methods, not reliability methods. However, I have never heard anyone worrying that their reliability is too high - you might worry that your scale is too long, but that (seems to be) the other side of the coin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to ensure that there is not a technique that solve such problems. I think the core of my problem is to reduce the length of the scale.

Comment: I would definitely think of your problem in terms of scale shortening.